# error undefined class TimeOfDay. when trying to use flutter time

Tags: dart, flutter

[image]when i use TimeOfDay i get the `error undefined class TimeOfDay`. it was previously working tho.I am trying to get the time,

```
TimeOfDay theTime = new TimeOfDay.now();
```

I don't understand why I get the error.

Comment: Could you give us more information?

Comment: I have imported material.dart, the keyword `TimeOfDay` gets underlined red anywhere I use it. however when I use `DateTime` I don't get the error

Comment: Could you put a screenshot?

Comment: when I change `TimeOfDay` to `theTimeTimeOfDay`, the error goes away. the debug console shows the error I get when I change TimeOfDay to `theTimeTimeOfDay`

Comment: I see that you have another var named theTimetimeofday and its working, where did you declare it?

Comment: Maybe you modified by error the class TimeOfDay, could you open the file and close it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you made a mistake and modified the class `TimeOfDay` inside `time.dart`, sometimes it happens.
Could you check the source code of the class `theTimeTimeOfDay` ? because it should not exists.

The class `time.dart` should start with something like this

```
@immutable
class TimeOfDay {
```

I'm 99% sure that you named it like this :

```
@immutable
class theTimeTimeOfDay {
```

Answer (score 1):

The class is defined in `material.dart` (it really is defined in a subfile, but it is part of `material.dart`).
If the class is undefined for you, you will need to import it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

TimeOfDay getCurrentTime() {
  return TimeOfDay.now();
}
```

Comment: I have imported material.dart, the keyword `TimeOfDay` gets underlined red anywhere I use it. however when I replace it with this class`theTimeTimeOfDay` the error goes away but code does not run